# php convert array to simple values

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this json output array in php:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "attributes": {
        "token": "3RfvqeIhdTpwRpYOnPOKXmJe0avkmyS7m2NNQF6T",
        "type": "access",
        "client_id": "gozfly-support-wvjausbh",
        "user_id": "2",
        "expires": 1513301754,
        "scopes": {
            "accounts.profile.basic": {},
            "accounts.profile.emailaddress": {}
        }
    }
}
```

I need to convert the scopes keys to simple values, like:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "attributes": {
        "token": "3RfvqeIhdTpwRpYOnPOKXmJe0avkmyS7m2NNQF6T",
        "type": "access",
        "client_id": "gozfly-support-wvjausbh",
        "user_id": "2",
        "expires": 1513301754,
        "scopes": {
            "accounts.profile.basic",
            "accounts.profile.emailaddress"
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Impossible. You can get `"scopes": [ "accounts.... ]` with square parentheses but not curly ones.

Comment: `json_decode()` cant get any simplier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDITED**
As @jh1711 comment above, the expected output is not a valid JSON string, it seems like a typo, I assume that expected output is:

**Expected Output:**

```
{
    "success": true,
    "attributes": {
        "token": "3RfvqeIhdTpwRpYOnPOKXmJe0avkmyS7m2NNQF6T",
        "type": "access",
        "client_id": "gozfly-support-wvjausbh",
        "user_id": "2",
        "expires": 1513301754,
        "scopes": [
            "accounts.profile.basic",
            "accounts.profile.emailaddress"
        ]
    }
}
```

**Solution:**

```
$data = <<<EOL
{
    "success": true,
    "attributes": {
        "token": "3RfvqeIhdTpwRpYOnPOKXmJe0avkmyS7m2NNQF6T",
        "type": "access",
        "client_id": "gozfly-support-wvjausbh",
        "user_id": "2",
        "expires": 1513301754,
        "scopes": {
            "accounts.profile.basic": {},
            "accounts.profile.emailaddress": {}
        }
    }
}
EOL;

$json = json_decode($data,true);
$json['attributes']['scopes'] = array_keys($json['attributes']['scopes']);

echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: As I said in my prev. comment; the output has square parentheses. [See](https://3v4l.org/iEFsj). Apart from that great answer even if it's code only.

Comment: @jh1711  I wasn't looking carefully, but the expected output is an invalid JSON string, it seems like a typo.

Comment: Either a typo, or a lack of understanding about JSON. I just didn't want to vote your answer without mentioning it.